# Spring spel - how to parse values into a hashmap

Tags: java, spring, spring-el

I'm writing an expression to get a values out of a GenericRecord to one object.
Tried to work with hashmap (the number of values is dynamic).
example:

```
expression.parse("new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(get('accountId'), get('anotherField'))");
Map result = expression.applyOn(someGenericRecord);
```

but it doesn't work.
I know all classes in expressions should be fully qualified (so that might be the problem) but I think there should be a cleaner way of extracting the values for using them later.

thanks